# Why SpringBoot RabbitMQ client auto shutdown connection to rabbitmq server

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, messagebroker, persistent-connection, tcp-keepalive

**

### geting rabbitmq connection error as follows.

**

2019-07-11 13:14:51.147.AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672> ERROR - TID[] UID[] MID[] CID[] - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=541, reply-text=INTERNAL_ERROR, class-id=0, method-id=0)
2019-07-11 13:14:51.831.bulkNotificationContainer-100> WARN  - TID[] UID[] MID[] CID[] - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=541, reply-text=INTERNAL_ERROR, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:742) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:732) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:671) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:625) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:102) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:549) ~[amqp-client-3.6.5.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]

***My spring-boot service using rabbitmq to send push notification asynchronously. So push payload publish/received via rabbitmq then send on FCM. However, this connection is working for last one year without any problem. But this morning rabbitmq server is restarted as follows***

1. rabbitmq stop
2. kill process bean ( related erlang )
3. rabbitmq start

after that we restart spring-boot service successfully, and health-api shows rabbit-up status.

but having error when trying to send push.

## application properties configuration.

> spring.rabbitmq.host=127.0.0.1 spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
>   spring.rabbitmq.username=rabbitadmin spring.rabbitmq.password=admin

## custom configuration

> rabbitmq.listeners.retry-policy = UNIFORM_RANDOM_DELAY
>   rabbitmq.listeners.max-interval=15000
>   rabbitmq.listener.push-router.concurrent-consumers=2
>   rabbitmq.listener.push-router.max-concurrent-consumers=10
>
> rabbitmq.binding.push-notification.queue.name=pushqueue
>   rabbitmq.binding.push-notification.exchange.name=pushexchange
>   rabbitmq.binding.push-notification.binding.routing-key=pushroute-binding

I want to publish/receive data to rabbitmq channel.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved after reinstalling the packages of rabbitmq.
Still dont know why this happened..